# Unconvert Text File from Binary Format

Tags: linux, encoding

I've got a rather large CSV file (~700MB) which I know to consist of lines of 27-character alpha-numeric hashes; no commas or anything fancy. Somehow, during its migration from Windows to Linux (via winSCP and then a few regular SCPs), it has converted into some kind of binary format I am unfamiliar with.

If I open the file in vi, everything appears fine, and it says [converted] at the bottom, although I know it's not a line endings issue (and dos2unix doesn't help). If I 'head' the file, it looks proper except for a "ÿþ" at the beginning of the first line. If I open up the file in nano, however, I see the "ÿþ" at the start and then "^@" before every character (even newlines and EoF).

If I try to re-save or copy the file (say via: head file.csv > short.txt), this special encoding is preserved. I copied the first ten lines out of vi (which displays it properly) into my Windows clipboard via my SSH client, then pasted it into a new text file, test.txt. This file is visually identical when opened in vi (and similar through 'head', minus the "ÿþ"), although it's roughly half of the filesize. Additionally,

```
file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text
file short.txt
short.txt:
```

I have no idea what format this once-text file got converted to (it's notoriously hard to search the internet for symbols), but surely there must be some way to convert it back. Any ideas?

Comment: It might help to post `short.txt` somewhere online and link to it so we have a sample to work with. It sounds like some sort of text encoding change (ASCII to UCS-2? just a wild guess) but I couldn't really say for sure without seeing a bit of the data.

Comment: http://home.comcast.net/~hammerbro/example.tgz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ÿþ" could be a Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) and the ^@ could be the first byte of each 16-bit Unicode character.

Use recode or iconv to convert it from UTF-16 to ASCII.

Comment: Thanks a billion! That did the trick with short.txt, although I suspect it's gonna take a little while on the full size data set.